# Azure App Registration - Missing api permission options for Office 365 Management APIs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-app-registration

I would like to know how to enable ActivityReports and ThreatIntelligence permission in the O365 management apis for app registrations?
I see only Activity Feed and ServiceHealth by default. Are ActivityReports and ThreatIntelligence part of any licensed features like Defender for 365?
If anyone has enabled please share the steps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These permissions were deprecated some time ago

```
ActivityReports.Read
ThreatIntelligence.Read
```

[image]

The above screenshot was taken from an older version of this document

[Get started with Office 365 Management APIs / Specify the permissions your app requires to access the Office 365 Management APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis#specify-the-permissions-your-app-requires-to-access-the-office-365-management-apis)